# Can I debug my C# Visual Studio program in Mac?

Tags: osx, c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a Mac and I download Visual Studio. I write my code but the VS is want to use terminal for debugging. But terminal of course can't open and debug the file as a CMD can. (I only got an error message).

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Is it a .NET Core app? Visual Studio should be able to debug C# out of the box. What is the error message you get? Do you try to debug from the terminal, or directly from Visual Studio?

Comment: The problem is, I want to run a Console application because we are programming in this format. I get the error message in the terminal after I try to debug from the Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok. What does the error message say?